# Small kubernetes volumes with google persistent disk

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I need small persistent volumes of around 50 Mb for my pods/containers.
I'm using gce persistent disks as persistent storage for google container engine but I can't create disks smaller than 1 GB

I've created the disk:

```
  gcloud compute disks create disk2 --size=1 --zone=us-central1-a
```

and created volume and volume claim with kubectl from my yaml files.

What I have trouble understanding is the size in the volume.yaml: if I put a size bigger then 1Gi or a size smaller than 1Gi everything is working fine, so what is the purpose of size in a volume config.
Also the describe pv has:

```
Source:
    Type:   GCEPersistentDisk (a Persistent Disk resource in Google Compute Engine)
    PDName: disk1
    FSType: ext4
    Partition:  0
    ReadOnly:   false
```

Can I change the partition here and partition the disk into smaller chunks ? I couldn't find how to declare the partition number in volume.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Platform doesn't support smaller sizes no matter what you do, unfortunately.

As for k8s side, no you can't partition the disk (a volume is supposed to be directly mountable, so GCE-PD provider gives you single volume back), and even then GCP doesn't support multiple writers to single volume, even if you have necessary support in kernel.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, what about the size defined in a volume yaml? I know that in a VolumeClaim config file, the size is the minumum size of the volume  to be match/bounded but for the Volume I saw no purpose in declaring the size  (at least not in working with google PD)

Comment: @isf85 from my understanding it's used by some of the volume plugins and storage classes, but not all, and in this case clearly shouldn't be needed